# Fira Sans installation in Latex

Tags: fonts

Latex noob here.

Is there any well explained way to install Fira Sans in LaTeX?

The [README file](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/fira/) says:

> To install this package on a TDS-compliant TeX system download the
>   file "tex-archive"/install/fonts/fira.tds.zip where the preferred
>   URL for "tex-archive" is http://mirrors.ctan.org. Unzip the archive
>   at the root of an appropriate texmf tree, likely a personal or local
>   tree. If necessary, update the file-name database (e.g., texhash).
>   Update the font-map files by enabling the Map file fira.map.

But there's some instruction that I did wrong, and the LaTeX keep accusing

> "! LaTeX Error: File `FiraSans.sty' not found."

Any help would be appreciated.
(Sorry for any grammar mistake)

Comment: What operating system and wqhat TeX distribution do you have installed?

Comment: Usually you don't need to install packages manually (unzip files, update database etc.) The LaTeX distribution offers a package manager which does all that for you. I really don't understand why package documentations include this, it only serves to confuse newbies.

Comment: I'm running Ubuntu;

~$ latex -v
pdfTeX 3.1415926-1.40.10-2.2 (TeX Live 2009/Debian)
kpathsea version 5.0.0

Comment: Unfortunately, your TeX Live installation is too old to include `fira` which was added to TeX Live 2013, I think. But TL 2009 is really quite old anyway and you would probably be better off with a more current distribution. Does Ubuntu offer a more recent option?

Comment: Just for reference, in Ubuntu you can install it with `sudo apt install texlive-fonts-extra`

Comment: sudo tlmgr install fira