# Xelatex Fontspec Cannot Find Fonts

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec, sharelatex

I've been working with a large document in Sharelatex for some time and I kept getting a fontspec error that it could not find the font file.  However, despite this error message the document kept compiling normally, that is until I switched the font to Garamond.  Now the document will only compile the sans-serif portion of the document.

Below is my MWE without the sans serif portion.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage[paperwidth=7.5in, paperheight=9.25in, top=1in,   bottom=1.375in, left=1in, right=1in]{geometry}
\setlength{\parindent}{2em}

%Fonts
\usepackage{fontspec}
 %This is ShareLaTeX Specific (or if the fonts are not installed in your system)
%-----------------------------------------------------------------------
% Garamond
\setmainfont[BoldFont=GARABD.otf,ItalicFont=GARAIT.otf]{GARAMOND.otf}

\begin{document}
Something is wrong! I am momentarily blinded and confused by moving, overlapping, translucent images that overwhelm my vision of the book I am reading. The room I sit in is visually a frenetic whirling mess. Abject fear grips me, first at the base of my spine, then it rips up my spine to my cortex and beyond. \par

\end{document}
```

Any ideas of how to fix this?  I've tried altering the file names, but this has produced no result.

Comment: Normally, you have to indicate only the name of the font family (not the name of the .otf file. Did you check the family name, as it is known by your system?

Comment: The problem here is that, by using ShareLatex, I have to upload the files off the system and then provide the file name.  That's why I included the .otf, since it doesn't seem to work without it.

Comment: They have an example of this here: https://www.sharelatex.com/project/578e6a78e0a7f0c46bcd6add

Comment: Fixed it, for some reason it demands that I change the font name that SharLatex gives it to the one that matches the computer's name for it.

Comment: for me the reason was because of read permission, fixed with `chmod +rw`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With `setmainfont` you're essential building *case-sensitive* font paths.

- Path=working directory for fonts
- BoldFont=filename segment of path
- ItalicFont=filename segment of path
- Extension=file extension of path

You're code does not work because you are telling fontspec to look in all paths like this *(example shows paths for bold font)*:

```
/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/GARABD.otf/GARAMOND.otf
/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/fonts/truetype/GARABD.otf/GARAMOND.otf
/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/GARABD.otf/GARAMOND.otf
... any other font directory in your environment/GARABD.otf/GARAMOND.otf
```

## TeX Default Known Font Path Segments

On Unix-based computers, you can figure out the TeX font folders with:

```
cat $(kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFSYSVAR)/fonts/conf/texlive-fontconfig.conf
```

which evaluates to `/home/texlive/2016/texmf-var/fonts/conf` for 2016, or for the appropriate year of your installed version.

Otherwise `fontspec` does have an automatic path finding mechanism for system fonts, where you can just do `\setmainfont{Arial}`, but this is not as explicit and therefore in my experience leads to problems with cross-platform or cross-computer compatibility.

See [How do I load a texlive font with fontspec?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/313837/how-do-i-load-a-texlive-font-with-fontspec)

## Empowering YOU to DO it Yourself

Find folder where you files reside (without knowing your OS, I will just make up something)

Given fonts are in same folder with these names:

```
/Library/Fonts/GARABD.otf
/Library/Fonts/GARAIT.otf
/Library/Fonts/GARAMOND.otf
```

How would I set up `fontspec` for this?

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[%
  Path = /Library/Fonts/ ,
  UprightFont = MOND ,
  BoldFont = BD ,
  ItalicFont = IT ,
  Extension = .otf
]{GARA} % {contains only what is common among all file names (usually basename of font family)}
```

---

## Notes

Many pro fonts use dashes in their file names to separate the variants, so you'll often see the following:

```
/Library/Fonts/DejaVuSansCondensed.ttf
/Library/Fonts/DejaVuSans.ttf
/Library/Fonts/DejaVuSans-ExtraLight.ttf
/Library/Fonts/DejaVuSansCondensed-Bold.ttf
/Library/Fonts/DejaVuSans-BoldOblique.ttf
/Library/Fonts/DejaVuSansCondensed-Oblique.ttf
/Library/Fonts/DejaVuSansCondensed-BoldOblique.ttf
/Library/Fonts/DejaVuSans-Oblique.ttf
/Library/Fonts/DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf
```

How would i set this up? Well, unfortunately `fontspec` does not support all of those fonts simultaneously, so I might either settle for less and  use `\setmainfont` or load them all by breaking them up into families e.g. `\newfontfamily\dejavucondensed` `\newfontfamily\dejavu` `\newfontfamily\dejavulight`.

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\dejavu[%
  Path = /Library/Fonts/ ,
  UprightFont = ,
  BoldFont = -Bold ,
  ItalicFont = -Oblique ,
  Extension = .ttf
]{DejaVuSans} % {contains only what is common among all file names (usually basename of font family)}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `\set*font` commands should accept a parameter `Path=[Path]` that points to the directory containing the files. This is only relevant if using fonts that are not known to the system. Otherwise you should provide the name of the font family as noted by bernard (first comment).