# fontawesome package not working with xelatex

Tags: xetex, fontawesome

Consider the following minimal example:

```
% !TEX program = xelatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontawesome}

\begin{document}
\faTwitter{} Some Text \faLinkedin
\end{document}
```

On my MacTeX 2016 basic system (up to date), the icons are missing in the PDF and I get the following error message:

```
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
/usr/local/texlive/2016basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontawesome/fontawesome.sty:45: fontspec error: "font-not-found"
! 
! The font "FontAwesome" cannot be found.
! 
! See the fontspec documentation for further information.
! 
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................
```

The example does work when I change the engine to

```
% !TEX program = latex
```

or

```
% !TEX program = luatex
```

I don't have the font installed on my system because according to the documentation the package should use the font bundled with the package (which obviously works with `latex` and `luatex`, but not with `xelatex`).

Comment: On linux and similar systems xetex can't find fonts in the texmf tree by name unless you add them first to your fontconfig configuration. See https://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html#x1-340003.4.4 and e.g. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/257231/using-the-tex-live-fonts-in-xelatex.

Comment: These instructions only work for Linux systems. I didn't find this information on the MacTeX website - could you point me to the relevant steps?

Comment: Hm. Isn't a mac a linux system? In any case I have windows, so can't help you with the details.

Comment: No, not really - they're both Unix, but differ in many aspects. Thanks anyway, I guess since this is a xelatex-related issue, I'll just switch to lualatex, which works just fine :-).

Comment: Sure what I mean: both are unix and the fontconfig should work similar.

Comment: No, fontconfig on Linux and Mac seem to be fundamentally different, since e.g. `fc-cache` doesn't exist. Anyway, I guess switching to `lualatex` seems to be the solution.

Comment: And the code above works fine on ubuntu using xelatex without change and without me having done anything additional to make that happen.

Comment: @JPI nice - that's how it should be. Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to be the case for all Linux distributions, since it is not working on my Arch Linux out of the box.

Comment: @cbrnr here are some MacTex specific instructions: https://tug.org/mactex/TeXLive2018+Changes.pdf (linked from https://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html#x1-340003.4.4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132888/fontawesome-font-not-found), all I had to do to get it to work with `xelatex` was install the FontAwesome font on my machine (e.g. by downloading it from [here](http://fontawesome.io/) and installing the file `FontAwesome.otf`).