# fontconfig doesn't list/find XITS font even after updating config

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec

I would like to use XITS/XITS Math within my LaTeX project (which uses XeTeX). Following the answers to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/257231/using-the-tex-live-fonts-in-xelatex), I created a file `/etc/fonts/conf.avail/76-texlive-fonts.conf` with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
<fontconfig>
    <dir>/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype</dir>
    <dir>/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/truetype</dir>
</fontconfig>
```

I had checked the above paths before to make sure that they are correct:

```
$ ls -l /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/xits
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 111280 Nov 25  2016 xits-bolditalic.otf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 151692 Nov 25  2016 xits-bold.otf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 115536 Nov 25  2016 xits-italic.otf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 248956 Nov 25  2016 xits-mathbold.otf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 530128 Nov 25  2016 xits-math.otf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 249372 Nov 25  2016 xits-regular.otf
```

Afterwards, I added a symlink to `/etc/fonts/conf.d/`:

```
$ ls -l /etc/fonts/conf.d/76-texlive-fonts.conf 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 35 Jan 10 13:15 /etc/fonts/conf.d/76-texlive-fonts.conf -> ../conf.avail/76-texlive-fonts.conf
```

…and ran `$ fc-cache -fv`. Its output, among others was:

```
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/xits: caching, new cache contents: 6 fonts, 0 dirs
```

Still, when I run `fc-list | grep -i xits` now, there is no output and compiling the below MWE gives the following error, as expected:

```
…
main.tex:11: !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! [\setmainfont{XITS}]
main.tex:11: Font TU/XITS(0)/m/n/12=XITS at 12.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file or installed font not found. [\setmainfont{XITS}]
…
main.tex:12: !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! [\setmathfont{XITS Math}]
main.tex:12: Font TU/XITSMath(0)/m/n/12="XITS Math/OT" at 12.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file or installed font not found.
…
```

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}


\setmainfont{XITS}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}

\begin{document}
  Hello! Some math: $y = f(x)$

\end{document}
```

I would very much appreciate any pointers to how I could fix or at least debug this problem!

---

**[UPDATE]:** Turns out *none* of the fonts in `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/` show up in `fc-list`: The output of `$ fc-list | grep /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts` is completely empty. Nevertheless, dozens of fonts get recognized when running `sudo fc-cache -fv | grep /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts`. What is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

I was being a moron: I ran `fc-cache` as root and `fc-list` as a regular user without realizing that the cache would then be built for the root user and not the regular user. Running both commands as regular user fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

for `xetex` use the file names instead of the symbolic names:

```
\setmainfont{xits-regular.otf}
\setmathfont{xits-math.otf}
\setmathfont[version=bold]{xits-mathbold.otf}
```